# Yocto: : does bitbake cleanall ,cleans dependencies as well

Tags: yocto, bitbake

bitbake cleanall 
Removes all output files, shared state cache, and downloaded source files for a target

It is not clear or documented if it cleans all build time dependencies as well

Comment: it is very unclear what you are actually asking and trying to say in your post.

Comment: no it does not clean the dependencies

Answer (score 20):

If you want to clean everything do,

```
bitbake world -c cleanall --continue
```

The `--continue` will ignore any dependency errors while cleaning. Continue as much as possible after an error.

Answer (score 11):

No, cleanall does not clean dependencies. eg

```
  bitbake -c cleanall core-image-minimal
```

only removes the output of that named recipe.

What i usually do to clean "everything" is running cleanall on the receipe "world":

```
bitbake -c cleanall world
```

If that fails because of unresolvable packages like that:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'sg3-utils' (but /home/blubb/meta-freescale/recipes-devtools/utp-com/utp-com_git.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it).
```

I just add the packages temporary to the ASSUME_PROVIDED variable like this :

```
bitbake -c cleanall world --ignore-deps=python-nativedtc-native --ignore-deps=sg3-utils
```

If nothing provides this packages it is unlikely that they where ever build.

Comment: When 'cleanall world' runs properly the normal progress bar is displayed with plenty of "*do_clean*" tasks

Answer (score 6):

Please read the mega-manual section [do_cleanall](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-tasks-cleanall) .

do_cleanall removes:

- all output files
- shared state (sstate) cache
- and downloaded source files for a target (i.e. the contents of DL_DIR).

You can run this task using BitBake as follows:

```
 $ bitbake -c cleanall <recipe-name>
```

If recipe name is not passed to cleanall task it does not work.

Comment: use "world" as recipe name if you want to cleanall for all the recipies.

Answer (score 3):

Removes all output files, shared state (sstate) cache, and downloaded source files for a target (i.e. the contents of DL_DIR). Essentially, the do_cleanall task is identical to the do_cleansstate task with the added removal of downloaded source files.

You can run this task using BitBake as follows:

```
 $ bitbake -c cleanall recipe
```

Typically, you would not normally use the cleanall task. Do so only if you want to start fresh with the do_fetch task.

Comment: +1 for the -c cleansstate explanation. Exactly what I needed: cleanup so everything gets rebuild but no need to redownload all packages.

Answer (score 1):

Other folks have already answered that bitbake does not automatically clean dependencies, but you can create an Inter-task dependency (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#inter-task-dependencies) to clean your dependencies if needed by adding a command to the recipe:

```
do_task[depends] = "recipe:task"
```

We've extended bitbake to build native recipes and automatically run unit tests during a build. In that case we need to clean the native recipe when cleaning the target so you could add:

```
do_clean[depends] = "${PN}-native:do_clean"
do_cleanall[depends] = "${PN}-native:do_cleanall"
do_cleansstate[depends] = "${PN}-native:do_cleansstate"
```

That solution falls a bit short because the native recipes will attempt to clean ${PN}-native-native, so you'll need a conditional to not apply if it's already native:

```
do_clean[depends] += "${@'' if bb.data.inherits_class('native', d) else '${PN}-native:do_clean'}"
do_cleanall[depends] += "${@'' if bb.data.inherits_class('native', d) else '${PN}-native:do_cleanall'}"
do_cleansstate[depends] += "${@'' if bb.data.inherits_class('native', d) else '${PN}-native:do_cleansstate'}"
```

Comment: Just asking ... aren't you missing an `s` in `do_cleanstate`? Shouldn't it be `do_cleansstate`?