# How to do a clean rebuild of Linux kernel modules in Yocto?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, yocto, bsp

I can `rm -rf tmp/ sstate-cache/ cache/` and run a whole Yocto build from scratch just fine, but I'd rather not rebuild everything (especially as packages like Qt can take some time).

I've tried:

`bitbake -c cleansstate linux-iwg15 kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv cryptodev-module`

Note: I've also tried `cleanall`, but it has the same result:

Either one of the kernel modules end up throwing this error once they get to `do_compile`:

```
  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

The `{build_dir}/tmp/work-shared/{MACHINE}/kernel-build-artifacts` folder actually contains `include/generated/autoconf.h`

I tried copying the contents of `kernel-build-artifacts` to `{build_dir}/tmp/work-shared/{MACHINE}/kernel-source` but still get the errors.

The `linux-iwg15` BitBake recipe is [here](https://github.com/cpboyd/meta-iwave/blob/thud/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-iwg15_4.14.78.bb).

Is there anything else that I should be cleaning before rebuilding the Linux kernel modules?

After a clean build, I did notice that `kernel-build-artifacts` contains `kernel` and `scripts` folders (as well as a symlink of `source` to `..\kernel-source`) that I don't remember being there when attempting to rebuild after running `bitbake -c cleansstate`.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585113/795910 . bitback -c cleanall should help you.

Comment: @OttavioCampana Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, as I mentioned, I've tried `bitbake -c cleanall linux-iwg15 kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv cryptodev-module` but still get the same error (it just has the added disadvantage of forcing a re-download of the source for each).

Comment: I see the same problem. If I build from scratch, the modules build cleanly, but if I just try to cleansstate the modules and rebuild, the kernel fails as you say. Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: @PhilBot I haven't been making as many kernel-specific changes recently and I've updated to Yocto 3.1 Dunfell. It does seem like recent Yocto releases have improved the process for rebuilds, so it may be worth trying to use Dunfell if possible.

Granted, a lot of BSPs don't provide official support for the most recent release, so I've also been using the "community" version of `meta-freescale` rather than my manufacturer's official BSP which is several years behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything else that I should be cleaning before rebuilding the Linux kernel modules?

Yes. `bitbake -c cleansstate make-mod-scripts`

Any kernel module recipe will contain `inherit module`. This references *meta/classes/module.bbclass* which contains `inherit module-base`. This references *meta/classes/module-base.bbclass* which contains:

```
# We do the dependency this way because the output is not preserved
# in sstate, so we must force do_compile to run (once).
do_configure[depends] += "make-mod-scripts:do_compile"
```

The **make-mod-scripts** recipe (at *meta/recipes-kernel/make-mod-scripts/make-mod-scripts.bb*) adds files to the *{build_dir}/tmp/work-shared/{MACHINE}/kernel-build-artifacts* directory. (This is referenced as `STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR` which is set in *conf/bitbake.conf*.)

Unfortunately, the kernel recipe will remove everything in the `STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR` directory, since that directory is added to the `do_shared_workdir[cleandirs]` variable in *meta/classes/kernel.bbclass*. This ends up removing files that *make-mod-scripts* put there as well.

Comment: You're welcome! This is actually a bug so I also submitted a bug report and it looks like its targeted to be fixed soon.
https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14317